# Angular: SVG attribute by event

Tags: angular, svg

How can I access the atrribute (e.g. fill) of an SVG object via an Angular event (e.g. mouseenter)?

I tried these variants without success.

```
<rect #rrr [attr.fill]="'green'" (mouseenter)="rrr.fill='red'/>

<rect #rrr [attr.fill]="'green'" (mouseenter)="rrr.attr.fill='red'/>

<rect #rrr [attr.fill]="'green'" (mouseenter)="rrr.attributes.fill='red'/>
```

I want to do it directly - so I use the #rrr. Dispatching it over a component-variable is working well - but not what I want.

```
<rect [attr.fill]="myvar == true ? 'red' : 'green'" (mouseenter)="myvar = true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of these options:

```
#rrr (mouseenter)="rrr.setAttribute('fill', 'red')"

#rrr (mouseenter)="rrr.style.fill = 'red'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use class to achieve that:

```
<rect [ngClass] = "{'red': myvar==true, 'green': myvar!=true}"/>
```

On your css:

```
.gren {
    fill:green;
}
.red{
   fill: red;
}
```

Comment: OP stated they didn't want to use a component variable like `myvar`.

Comment: With this method You could let your  html template more clean.

Comment: 1. Yes factually it could be, but OPs requirement doesn't align with the answer. 2. It could be more clean using ternary operator: `[ngClass]="myvar ? 'red' : 'green'"`.

Comment: It is look like more cleaner to me :).